# Frechet derivative of a nonlinear operator on Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, frechet-derivative

Consider a simple nonlinear operator $F:W^{2,2}(0,1)\to L^2(0,1)$ where $F: w \mapsto w^3$. Assume $F$ is Frechet differntiable with derivative $DF_{w}h=3w^2h$. To prove it, we need to show:
$$\frac{\|(w+h)^3-w^3-3w^2h\|_2}{\|h\|_{2,2}}\to0$$

This boils down to

$$\frac{\|h^3+3h^2w\|_2}{\|h\|_{2,2}}\to 0$$

Sobolev embedding theorem of $W^{2,2}\subset \subset L^6 $ tells us that
$$\frac{\|h^3\|_2}{\|h\|_{2,2}}\to 0$$
But the last part still remains to prove; that is; showing that
$$\frac{\|3h^2 w\|_2}{\|h\|_{2,2}}\to 0 \quad \forall w\in W^{2,2}$$
Please comment on this!

Comment: Shouldn't you be showing that $$\frac{\|(w+h)^3-w^3-3w^2h\|_{2}}{\|h\|_{2,2}}\to0\, ?$$

Comment: yep, my bad, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same embedding $W^{2,2}\hookrightarrow L^6$:
$$
\|h^2w \|_{L^2} \le \|h\|_{L^6}^2 \|w\|_{L^6} \le \|h\|_{W^{2,2}}^2\|w\|_{W^{2,2}}.
$$

Comment: How do you drive the first inequality? How do you split it into two norms?

Comment: H\"older inequality